# What is the fastest en passant checkmate after all other such captures?

Tags: problems, records, en-passant

I had an odd idea. What is the fastest way to checkmate via en passant after all other en passants have been completed?

Comment: I am not even sure I understand the question. You want to construct a game, where the maximum possible number of en passant moves has been made and the last en passant move is mate?

Comment: To be honest, I don't get the point of these questions. Where's the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addendmum 5/21/2021-It is done at last! I have finally found a way to achieve it in just **36 ply** as previously estimated. I am wholly certain that faster is not possible. This is because 32 plies alone are needed for all eight en passants, the White king must be on the second rank, and White must also fill in the king's square for the checkmate.

This self-imposed challenge. nearly 2.5 years later, has at last been completely solved.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 5/21/2021, Non-Unique Proof Game In 18.0 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. a4 d5 2. a5 b5 3. axb6 d4 4. c4 dxc3 5. d4 a5 6. d5 c5 7. dxc6 a4 8. b4 axb3 9. f4 g5 10. f5 e5 11. fxe6 g4 12. h4 gxh3 13. e4 h6 14. e5 f5 15. exf6 h5 16. Kf2 Qd3 17. Qe1 h4 18. g4 hxg3#
```

---

It turns out that at least a further ply can be shaved off of @DM's answer.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 4/29/2021, Non-Unique Proof Game In 18.5 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. a4 d5 2. a5 b5 3. axb6 d4 4. c4 dxc3 5. d4 a5 6. d5 a4 7. b4 axb3 8. Qd3 e5 9. h4 e4 10. f4 exf3 11. h5 g5 12. hxg6 h5 13. e4 h4 14. g4 hxg3 15. e5 f5 16. exf6 Kd7 17. Qe4 Na6 18. Bf4 c5 19. dxc6#
```

I am not sure if it is possible to shave off a further ply due to the need to cover the king's potential escape squares. But if it can be done, I think 36 ply is the fastest possible sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one try:

```
[FEN ""]
1.d4 b5 2.d5 c5 3.dxc6 b4 4.a4 bxa3 5.b4 d5 6.b5 a5 7.bxa6 d4 8.c4 dxc3 9.h4 f5 10.h5 g5 11.hxg6 f4 12.e4 fxe3 13.g4 Bb7 14.g5 h5 15.gxh6 e5 16.Ke2 e4 17.Qe1 Bc5 18.Nh3 Bxc6 19.f4 exf3#
```

While this probably isn't the fastest possible, it can't get *much* faster. There are 8 en passants possible, and each takes 4 half moves to set up and execute (advance to 4th rank, advance to 5th rank, opponent moves pawn, capture pawn.) Those 32 half moves takes you through move 16, and you obviously need other moves somewhere to make it be a checkmate.